# Reactjs Facebook Login

Tags: reactjs, facebook-login, google-signin

I am having issues with the facebook-login component in ReactJs, the code is exactly as is in the documentation, but still not working. Can you help me to figure out what I doing wrong?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import FacebookLogin from "react-facebook-login";

class Flogin extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    const responseFacebook = response => {
      console.log(response);
    };

    const componentClicked = data => {
      console.log(data);
    };
    return (
      <FacebookLogin
        appId="MY_APP_ID"
        autoLoad={true}
        fields="name,email,picture"
        onClick={componentClicked}
        callback={responseFacebook}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Flogin;
```

[Documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-facebook-login)

[image: Facebook and Google buttons]

[image: console messages]

Google login works perfectly good, but when I press the Facebook button login nothing happens.

Comment: Do you have application id in place? It seems to be an issue if there is missing app id.

Comment: yes I do, I didn’t post it here for security reasons

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, I used exactly your code and seems to work. Check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/fb-login-x8cex?file=/index.js):

```
<FacebookLogin
   appId="1088597931155576"
   autoLoad={true}
   fields="name,email,picture"
   onClick={componentClicked}
   callback={responseFacebook}
 />
```

I'm using `react-facebook-login 3.7.2`.